# Filter Newsprint in Gimp 2.10

Tags: gimp

In Gimp 2.10, the Filter "Newsprint" is no more available in the menu "Filter distorts". Does a plugin exist for providing this filter? I am using Ubuntu 18.04.4.

Answer (score 0):

It exists in gimp 2.10 in the menu **Filters** -> **Distorts** -> **Newsprint**

It is located almost at the bottom of the list of filters.

If you really do not have this filter, then try **Filters** -> **Reset all filters** option

or reinstall gimp:

```
sudo apt purge gimp && sudo apt autoremove && sudo apt install gimp
```

But if you want to try different filters, you could try G'MIC plugin:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gmic gimp-gmic
```

There's a huge number of different filters.

If after installing you could not launch gimp, then fix it by:

```
sudo apt purge lisudo apt purge libgegl-0.4-0
sudo apt install gimp-gmic
```

Comment: I applied your recommendations without effect. It made me reconsider my problem and I found out the following: as I am using the French version of Gimp 2.10, filter "newsprint" still exist under the name of "papier journal". Its original name "trame d'imprimerie" has changed from Gimp 1.8. Also, its position, now # 7, in the distort filters. Thanks.

Comment: It means that for French version of Gimp 2.10, filter "papier journal" (equivalent of newsprint) does exist in position # 7 in the distort filters. It differs from name and position from previous version of Gimp.

Comment: My issue is solved. Anyway, thanks for your input.